# Splitting up dynamic string in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following string in PHP:

```
System load: 0.0 Processes: 119 Usage of /: 0.8% of 226.04GB Users logged in: 1 Memory     usage: 4% IP address for eth0: 192.168.0.21 Swap usage: 0% Graph this data and manage this system at https://landscape.canonical.com/
```

I'm trying to split it up into strings for each value so I can get "0.0", "119", "0.8% of 226.04GB", "1", "4%", "192.168.0.21", "0%".

I did try using set locations in the string to pick out the data but realised it was no good as the values are dynamic and could change from being 1 to 4+ characters long at any time. Is there a way I can split these up using PHP? I was unable to find anything in the string function library. Thanks.

Comment: it's much easier to get this information from much more targeted (and easier to parse) commands like `uptime`, `df`, etc

Comment: If it's possible to get all of it from individual commands that would be a lot easier! I'll see if I can find them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/2kT

```
$input = 'System load: 0.0 Processes: 119 Usage of /: 0.8% of 226.04GB Users logged in: 1 Memory     usage: 4% IP address for eth0: 192.168.0.21 Swap usage: 0% Graph this data and manage this system at https://landscape.canonical.com/';

$results = array();

preg_match_all("/\d[^\s:]*/", $input, $results);
```

$results will look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.0
            [1] => 119
            [2] => 0.8%
            [3] => 226.04GB
            [4] => 1
            [5] => 4%
            [6] => 0
            [7] => 192.168.0.21
            [8] => 0%
        )

)
```

Comment: And /\d[^\s:]?/ in case you want to grab the "1" from Users logged in: column as well :)

Answer (score 0):

A sample regular expression that just grabs groups (untested):

```
System load: (\d+.\d) Processes: (\d+) Usage of /: (\d+.\d)% of (\w+) Users logged in: (\d+) Memory usage: (\d+%) IP address for eth0: (\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}) Swap usage: (\d+%) Graph this data and manage this system at https://landscape.canonical.com/
```

It's quite vulnerable to slight changes though, like extra spaces etc. It'd be much easier to just grab this information from different places, like `df`. Some even are available as standard PHP functions, like [`sys_getloadavg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-getloadavg.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'System load: 0.0 Processes: 119 Usage of /: 0.8% of 226.04GB Users logged in: 1 Memory     usage: 4% IP address for eth0: 192.168.0.21 Swap usage: 0% Graph this data and manage this system at https://landscape.canonical.com/';  

$regex = '/^(?:System\s+load\:\s+)(\d+\.\d+)(?:\s+Processes\:\s+)(\d+)(?:\s+Usage\s+of\s+\/\:\s+)(\d+\.\d+\%\sof\s\d+\.\d+GB)(?:\s+Users\s+logged\s+in\:\s+)(\d+)(?:\s+Memory\s+usage\:\s+)(\d+\%)(?:\s+IP\s+address\s+for\s+eth\d+\:\s+)(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(?:\s+Swap\s+usage\:\s+)(\d+\%)(?:\s+Graph\s+this\s+data.+)$/';  

preg_match_all($regex, $str, $x);  

echo '<pre>'.print_r($x, 1);
```

don't worry about spaces ;)

Comment: I just get a blank array for this!